# How to get list of changelists not yet integrated using P4J API?

Tags: perforce

I'm converting a Python script that calls 'p4 interchanges' (ie the command that returns changes not yet integrated into a branch) to use a JVM language. What P4J (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/) API can be used to reproduce the same functionality?

Comment: Did you have a look at `http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/option/server/GetInterchangesOptions.html`?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear how to use that. Looking at it a bit more, it looks like it's for the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Perforce support:

`GetInterchangesOptions` is for passing flags to the interchanges command, if needed.

Use one of the `server.getInterchanges()` methods.
I also recommend using the `IOptionsServer` interface rather than `IServer`.

For this `p4` command line:

```
p4 interchanges //depot/merges/main/... //depot/merges/release/...
```

I have this P4Java equivalent:

```
IOptionsServer server =
    ServerFactory.getOptionsServer("p4java://perforce:1666", null, null);

List<IChangelist> changes = server.getInterchanges(
    null,
    FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(new String[] {"//depot/merges/main/..."}),
    FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(new String[] {"//depot/merges/release/..."}),
    null);

for(IChangelist change : changes) {
    System.out.println(change.getId());
}
```